# Pass request context to serializer from Viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a case where the values for a serializer field depend on the identity of the currently logged in user.  I have seen how to add the user to the context when initializing a serializer, but I am not sure how to do this when using a ViewSet, as you only supply the serializer class and not the actual serializer instance.

Basically I would like to know how to go from:

```
class myModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = myModel.objects.all()
   permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
   serializer_class = myModelSerializer
```

to:

```
class myModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uploaded_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    special_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = myModel

    def get_special_field(self, obj):
        if self.context['request'].user.has_perm('something.add_something'):
           return something
```

Sorry if it wasn't clear, from the DOCs:
[Adding Extra Context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) 
Which says to do

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(account, context={'request': request})
serializer.data
```

But I am not sure how to do that automatically from the viewset, as I only can change the serializer class, and not the serializer instance itself.

Comment: Have you tried `self.context.get('request').user.has_perm("some.permission")` ?

Comment: Do you want `something` to be returned with other fields of serializer in the output?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, the problem is that self.context is empty in the serializer.

Comment: `AccountSerializer(account, context={'request': request})` was all I needed for my purpose

Comment: citynorman Where do u define request? I try to define request as: ```context={'request': { 'user': self.admins[0].user }}``` and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`GenericViewSet` has the `get_serializer_context` method which will let you update `context`:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

For Python 2.7, use `context = super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()`

Comment: Selecting this as the best answer.  I believe this would have solved my problem (if this is what my problem actually was).  Turns out I missed the fact that I was manually instantiating the serializer in this case, and it wasn't being routed by the viewset.  D'oh.

Comment: for me it says : `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: @Coderaemon did you fix that? That's what I get :/ context is not passed to serializer

Comment: @Bradley Neil Reed Do you have `self.request`?

Comment: The latest DRF includes `self.request` in the default context sent to serializers; you don't need to manually add it in.

Comment: For everyone who's getting the request KeyError: You can solve this is by initializing the serializer from the view with the request object as follows: serializer = serializers.RandomSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request':request}) Source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: @Syslo, please could you help me look into this, it is a similar question but the solution here doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers

Comment: Use `self.context.request` in 3.12.4.

Answer (score 20):

For **Function based views** you can pass `request` or `user` as follows:

```
serializer = ProductSerializer(context = {"request": request}, data=request.data)
```

Your `Serializer` may look like:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["id"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        print(f"User is: {user}")
```

Feel free to inform if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

just use get_serializer() in your viewsets

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
    deserializing input, and for serializing output.
    """
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: your ViewSet should be subclass of GenericViewSet

Answer (score 2):

Return parent context in overrided function `get_serializer_context` will make it easy to access request and its data.

```
 class myModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
       queryset = myModel.objects.all()
       permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
       serializer_class = myModelSerializer

       def get_serializer_context(self):
       """
       pass request attribute to serializer
       """
           context = super(myModelViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
           return context
```

This is very stable as every time we request viewset, it returns context as well.

Answer (score 1):

> the values for a serializer field depend on the identity of the currently logged in user

This is how I handle such cases in my ModelViewSet:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):

    user = self.request.user
    if user.username == 'myuser':
        serializer.data['myfield'] = 'something'

    serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this 2 line method in your class and you are good to go.

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {'request': self.request}
```

Answer (score 1):

since the posted answers had partial correctness, summarizing here in the interest of completeness.

1. override get_serializer_context..AND
2. use get_serializer in your views instead of manually calling the serializer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could fix it by replacing the serializer definition

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializerClass

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True) #replace this
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

replace the serializer with

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
```