# Django REST Framework: how serializer context works?

Tags: django-rest-framework

It's a pretty standard task in Django REST Framework to supply additional `args`/`kwargs` to a serializer to set values of fields set not via `request.data`, but via the value in url parameters or cookies. For instance, I need to set `user` field of my Comment model equal to `request.user` upon POST request. Those additional arguments are called context.

Several questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038742/pass-request-context-to-serializer-from-viewset-in-django-rest-framework), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework)) on StackOverflow suggest that I override `get_serializer_context()` method of my `ModelViewSet`. I did and it doesn't help. I tried to understand, what's wrong, and found out that I don't understand from the source code, how this context system is supposed to work in general. (documentation on this matter is missing, too)

Can anyone explain, where serializer adds context to normal request data? I found two places, where it saves the values from context.

1. [serializer.save()](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L180), method, which mixes kwargs with validated data, but it is usually called with no arguments (e.g. by [ModelMixins](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L70)).
2. [fields.`__new__()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L565), which caches args and kwargs, but it seems that nobody ever reads them later.

Answer (score 31):

Whenever you use generic views or viewsets, DRF(3.3.2) adds `request` object, `view` object and `format` to the serializer `context`. You can use `serializer.context` to access, lets say `request.user` in the serializer.

This is added when `get_serializer_class()` is called. Inside that, it calls `get_serializer_context()` method where all these parameters are added to its context.

**DRF source code for reference:**

```
class GenericAPIView(views.APIView):
    """
    Base class for all other generic views.
    """

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)    

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

Comment: That much I figured, but what happens later? I can't see, where Serializer makes use of this context to fill the fields with values, taken from it.

Comment: In normal cases the context won't be used by a serializer.  If we want to access `request` object in a serializer, we will use `self.context.get('request')`.  Also, in any serializer field's `to_representation`  method, we can access the `context` using `self.context` variable.

Comment: (From [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) )One common case to include `context` is if you're using a serializer that includes hyperlinked relations, which requires the serializer to have access to the current request so that it can properly generate fully qualified URLs.

Comment: @Rahul Gupta could you help me look into this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers

Answer (score 2):

> to set values of fields set not via request.data, but via the value in url parameters or cookies. For instance, I need to set user field of my Comment model equal to request.user upon POST request.

This is how I handle both cases in my ModelViewSet:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):

    # Get article id from url e.g. http://myhost/article/1/comments/
    # obviously assumes urls.py is setup right etc etc
    article_pk = self.kwargs['article_pk']
    article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(), pk=article_pk)

    # Get user from request
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user, article=article)
```

Unfortunately the nested objects is not standard for DRF but that's besides the point. :)