# Can I drop Serializers from DRF completely?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use Django REST Framework with MongoDB.

I tried to use Mongoengine with Django-REST-Framework-Mongoengine and it's not working (or I do something wrong, but documentation's missing, so I don't know, how to do it right).

Now I'm trying to get rid of Mongoengine layer completely and directly use PyMongo.

Essentially, to create each enpoint in classical Django REST Framework, you need a triplet:

`(ViewSet, Serializer, Model)`

With PyMongo I'll drop `Model` layer completely. The question is: do I have to keep the `Serialier` level? Can I create a `ViewSet` without `Serializer` at all and have `Browsable API` working? Killer-features of Django REST Framework for me are `Browsable API` and request `Parsers`.

Does `Browsable API` absolutely require `Serializer`?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `Mongoengine` layer  instead of `Pymongo`. Maybe you should add the code which you are trying in DRF-MongoEngine which is not working.

Comment: @RahulGupta I do. I reported that code as a bug on their github: https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/173 and in fact found a workaround to get it working (lost some validation though). But to think, the whole mongoengine thing is just a replication of django Models for mongo, which you don't need - pymongo query language is not worse than django query language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the Browsable API, you'll need a serializer.
You can do without serializers but you'll loose that feature - though json or form are still working.

I wrote some lines about the [use of Django REST framework without models](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/django-rest-framework-viewset-when-you-don-t-have-a-model-335a0490ba6f) if that can help.

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. So, I can live without serializers, I'll just loose forms in Browsable API.

Comment: Xavier, if it's not troublesome to you, could you look into this question, too, I'm really stuck there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275270/django-rest-framework-how-serializer-context-works

Comment: Bob, you may want to look at [this post](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/) from Tom Christie. It gives some idea about how to decouple things with DRF.

Comment: I had a look at your other question and Rahul Gupta's answer is correct.