# is serializer necessary in Django RestFramework when operating with external db

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, pymongo

I have requirement where in, I am suppose to build REST API, Database that i have to use is MongoDB and is not a part of the current Django project, it is managed and handled by some other team.

For current Django project, I use MySQL. below is how i write API's with current Django project with MySQL

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serilaizers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

but for MongoDB new requirement, i use PyMongo to interact with MongoDB

views.py

```
import pymongo


class EmpViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request):
        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
        mydb = myclient["external_database"]
        mycol = mydb["employee"]
    
        result = mycol.find_one({'emp_id': 123})
        return Response({"result": result}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

it is working fine with above code(it is not the exact code, similar implemention).

i need to do all CRUD operation on MongoDB. I am unaware that serialzers is needed for this or not?

if needed then, how will i write the serializer for it, since the result from the MongoDB query may give dynamic schema.

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**got the answer here**

[Can I drop Serializers from DRF completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304791/can-i-drop-serializers-from-drf-completely)

will go without serializers.

Comment: have you gone though: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @from_the_docs I know about Mongo-Engine, but this DB is not in my current django project, DB and its collections are handled by some other team, I am not suppose to do makemigrations and migrate to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use django-mongodb-engine or similar to allow ORM to communicate to the DB so that you can reap the benefits of the django magic. Otherwise you should manually create helper_functions and subclass serializers to add your own custom logic to them.