# How to fetch data by foreign key in Django serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-serializer

I'm stuck on fetching data with a related foreign key. I am doing some kind of validation in which the create method would be allowed depending on the `requesterid` to be POSTed.

This is my `userTable` model:

```
class userTable(models.Model):
userid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
userroleid = models.ForeignKey(roleTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Another model is the `requestTable`

```
class requestTable(models.Model):
rid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
requesterid =  models.ForeignKey(userTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(...)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class RequestCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
parts=PartSerializer(many=True)
class Meta:
    model = requestTable
    fields = ['rid','requesterid', (...)]

def create(self, instance, validated_data):
    if instance.requesterid.userroleid == 3:   #how can i fetch my `requesterid` data?
        parts_data = validated_data.pop('parts')
        request = requestTable.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for part_data in parts_data:
            partsTable.objects.create(request=request, **part_data)
        return request
    raise ValidationError("Sorry! Your role has no permission to create a request.")
```

Also, I'm quite confused if I should do validation in serializers, or views. If I do it in views, it just throws the `ValidationError`, and it doesn't seem to enter the if condition.

For reference, here's my views:

```
class RequestListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = requestTable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.data.get('requesterid__userroleid') == '3':
            write_serializer = RequestCreateSerializer(data=request.data)        
            write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(write_serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(write_serializer.data)
            return Response({"Request ID": write_serializer.instance.requestid, "Parts ID": [p.partsid for p in write_serializer.instance.parts.all()]},headers=headers)
        raise ValidationError("Sorry! Your role has no permission to create a request.")
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: do you want user instance on serialzier from view?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? What I'm trying now is to fetch my `requesterid` on serializer. @lordstock

Comment: you can get context from view to your serilizer  in this way `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038742/pass-request-context-to-serializer-from-viewset-in-django-rest-framework`